# Pass arguments to signal handler in C

Tags: c, multithreading, timer, signals, handler

How can I pass arguments (e.g. a pointer to a struct) to a signal handler? 
I'm writing a multithread application, so I cannot use global variables

I associate a timer to each thread. When timer expires I have to update a struct (each thread has a different struct).

How can I do?

Comment: How about using a thread-local variable then?

Comment: How can I pass a thread-local variable to signal handler?

Comment: Can you be more clear? Tell us what is the type of signal? And what is the format of output you desire!

Comment: I'm writing a client server application. I use UDP socket, so I have to handle packet loss and retransmission. Server is multithreaded. Each thread has a timer associated to packet transmitted. I create timer by using timer_create() and timer_settime() and I use SIGUSR1. When timer expires I have to retransimit, so I need to pass thread specific data to the signal handler to retransmit and restart timer.

Comment: Use timerfd and stick the alarming FD in the same poll loop as the I/O FD?

Answer (score 1):

The way the signal handler is called by the system is fixed -- there's no way to change it and add an additional user pointer.  So if you want to get additional data into the signal handler, the only way to do it is with a global variable (which could be thread-local).

However, if you are trying to use `timer_create` with threads, you are much better off using `SIGEV_THREAD` rather than `SIGEV_SIGNAL`.  The latter sends the signal to the *process* rather than the *thread*, so it might be caught by any thread in the process.

Comment: glibc appears to allocate _Thread_local variables lazily and dynamically (with succeed-or-die malloc calls, which I don't like very much), so it seems at least the first access to a _Thread_local could be AS-unsafe. I couldn't find more info,on this, though.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX timers allow to specify the details of how your process will be notified of an expiration using the `struct sigevent` structure documented in [sigevent(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/sigevent).

To pass context info to the siggnal handler for the generated signal, you can set the `.sigev_value.sival_ptr` member, which your signal handler will then be able to retrieve (you'll need to set the signal handler via the `.sa_sigaction` member of `struct sigaction`, while making sure the structure's `.sa_flags` is ORred with `SA_SIGINFO`).